# average of two columns for each row in pandas

Tags: pandas

I am a bit new in pandas and i have a questions
I want to divide two columns by row.

More about the data: I have several companies, who sold n items for m revenue

```
company #   nr of items revenue 
1               30      32.0          
2               40      59.3     
3               22.0    64
```

I want to calculate

```
    company #   nr of items revenue average price per item
1               30           32.0          
2               40           59.3     
3               22.0         64
```

average price per item = revenue /nr of items

I tried

```
df[['company','revenue','nr of items']].groupby('company')['revenue'].sum()/['nr of items'].sum()
```

but it doesn't work...
Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Your two dataframes have identical numbers? Is that a typo? Also if you think grouping by company is important, I suggest you add multiple rows of the same company to your sample data to make this clear.

Comment: yes, I want to calculate the third column:

Comment: The average price is per company right?

Comment: If you are **just** looking for this `average price per item = revenue /nr of items`, then you should do `df['avg_price'] = df['revenue']/df['nr_items']`

Comment: Otherwise `df1 = df.groupby(['company'], as_index=False).sum()` and then `df1['avg_price'] = df1['revenue']/df1['nr_items']`

Comment: *"yes, I want to calculate the third column"* -- then please calculate it manually and add it to your second df

Comment: thanks! I tried the second solution and it worked! ( I wanted a result for each company)

Answer (score 0):

The flaw in your code is that:

```
df[['company','revenue','nr of items']].groupby('company')['revenue'].sum()
```

is a proper expression (run it alone), computing the sum of revenues by company
(a *Series*).

Then you attempt to divide it by `['nr of items'].sum()`.

And here the exception is raised, because `['nr of items']` is a plain,
*pythonic* list of strings, which has no attribute named *sum*
(as stated in the error message).

## How to compute it properly

Assume that *df* contains:

```
   company  nr of items  revenue
0        1         30.0     32.0
1        1         20.0     41.0
2        2         40.0     59.3
3        2         12.0     82.1
4        3         22.0     64.0
5        3         22.5     18.0
```

(several rows for each company).

**First variant - stepwise**

The first step is to compute totals by company:

```
totalByComp = df.groupby('company').sum()
```

The result is:

```
         nr of items  revenue
company                      
1               50.0     73.0
2               52.0    141.4
3               44.5     82.0
```

And then compute the expected result (average revenue by item), dividing
*revenue* by *nr of items*:

```
result = totalByComp.revenue / totalByComp['nr of items']
```

getting:

```
company
1    1.460000
2    2.719231
3    1.842697
dtype: float64
```

**Or shorter** (all in one) - apply a lambda function to each group:

```
df.groupby('company').apply(lambda grp: grp.revenue.sum() / grp['nr of items'].sum())
```